# Generalising the creation of a formula in R

Tags: r, formula, modeling, tilde

I'm trying to create a formula in R, of the form

`Output~Var1+Var2+Var3`

For use in a model. The way it seems to work is that you give Variable name you want to predict,tilde,the variable names you want to use as predictors and then in a later argument you give the data frame containing observations of those variables. The data frame I'm using, however, has quite a few Variables in it, and I don't want to type them all out. These variables also change names relatively frequently, so it would be an effort to keep changing my code. In essence, I want to know how to write

```
Output~(All the variables that aren't the output)
```

Although I also need to exclude some other Variables as well.
Sorry to make it quite so clear I don't know what's going on, ?formula didn't help too much, and this isn't like any other programming or R structure I've seen before.

Thanks for any help,

N

Comment: `Output~.` puts everything else on the RHS

Comment: Thanks. How can I exclude another variable? Will !Variable do it?

Comment: Just subset the dataframe given to the `data` parameter to the variables you wish to include.

Comment: or use `Output~.-excluded_var`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I found a much better solution: the function

```
reformulate(termlabels = colnames(InputTable), response = 'Prediction')
```

Will create a formula from the strings you provide. Manipulate colnames as you like to  dynamically choose which variables are used in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the ?formula documentation provides one possible answer. It is, however, extremely 'hacky', and one of the least pleasant ways I can imagine accomplishing this

```
## Create a formula for a model with a large number of variables:
xnam <- paste0("x", 1:25)
(fmla <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+"))))
```

ie, you just paste toghether a string and use that as your formula.